# .NET: New project with tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I remember when I first installed Visual Studio 2010 and created a new C# project, I would get a prompt that asked me if I wanted to create a project for tests associated with my new project.

Today, however, I don't get this prompt.

How do I add the default test project with a new test?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will not query you with a dialog to create a test project when you create normal projects. However, ASP.NET MVC projects are designed to be developed test driven and thus this dialog will appear for MVC projects.